# How to Import query from file into procedure

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I am generating a procedure to check for all data issues like duplicates in database tables.So the format is as such explained below:

```
CREATE TABLE <test_table>    --table i created to save the procedure test results
(
RUN_ID number,
QUERY_ID    NUMBER,
QUERY_NAME VARCHAR(1000),
QUERY_STATUS     VARCHAR(10),
MAIN_TABLE_NAME   VARCHAR(500),
EXP_RESULT  VARCHAR(4000),
ACT_RESULT  VARCHAR(4000),
RUN_ON_DT DATE,
TEST_LEVEL_GIVEN NUMBER,
START_TIME_WID NUMBER,
END_TIME_WID NUMBER,
TEST_QUERY  VARCHAR(4000),
QUERY_DESC  VARCHAR(4000),
Comments    VARCHAR(4000)
)




create or replace
    PROCEDURE PROC_TESTING (TEST_LEVEL IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0 , START_WID IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0, END_WID  NUMBER DEFAULT 0) IS
    --TEST_LEVEL=0 IS TO RUN ALL QUERIES : FULL PROCEDURE
    --TEST_LEVEL=1 IS FOR BASIC QUERIES
    --TEST_LEVEL=2 IS FOR DIMENSION QUERIES
    --TEST_LEVEL=3 IS FOR FACT QUERIES
    --TEST_LEVEL=4 IS FOR .... QUERIES
    --TEST_LEVEL=5 IS FOR .... QUERIES

V_RUN_ID NUMBER;
V_QUERY_ID    NUMBER;
V_QUERY_NAME VARCHAR(1000);
V_QUERY_STATUS     VARCHAR(10);
V_MAIN_TABLE_NAME   VARCHAR(500);
V_EXP_RESULT  VARCHAR(4000);
V_ACT_RESULT  VARCHAR(4000);
V_RUN_ON_DT DATE;
V_TEST_QUERY  VARCHAR(4000);
V_QUERY_DESC  VARCHAR(4000);
V_COMMENTS    VARCHAR(4000);



BEGIN

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'STARTING THE TESTING PROC ON ' || SYSDATE );

SELECT  RUN_ID.NEXTVAL  INTO V_RUN_ID FROM DUAL;

SELECT SYSDATE INTO V_RUN_ON_DT FROM DUAL;

IF TEST_LEVEL<>1 and TEST_LEVEL<>2 and TEST_LEVEL<>0 
Then
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Conditions not met' || SYSDATE );
  return;
end if;



IF TEST_LEVEL=1 or TEST_LEVEL=2 or TEST_LEVEL=0 
Then
  V_QUERY_ID:=1;
  V_QUERY_NAME:='Duplicates check';
  V_MAIN_TABLE_NAME:='<table_to_be_tested>';
  V_QUERY_DESC:='checking for duplicates'; 

  -- Expected results
  V_EXP_RESULT := 0; 
  -- Actual results

  select count(*) into V_ACT_RESULT
  from (select  id1
                      , id2
                      , EFFECTIVE_FROM_DT
                      , EFFECTIVE_TO_DT
                      , update_dt       
                      , row_number() over (partition by 
                      id1
                      , id2
                      , EFFECTIVE_FROM_DT
                      , EFFECTIVE_TO_DT
            order by integration_id ) as occurrence
            from <table_to_be_tested>) x
  where occurrence > 1;

  IF V_EXP_RESULT = V_ACT_RESULT THEN 
    V_QUERY_STATUS:='PASS';
  ELSE
    V_QUERY_STATUS:='FAIL';
  END IF; 

END IF;



Insert into <test_table>     --going to store all above explained values into this table
(
RUN_ID ,
QUERY_ID ,
QUERY_NAME ,
QUERY_STATUS   ,
MAIN_TABLE_NAME ,
EXP_RESULT,
ACT_RESULT  ,
RUN_ON_DT,
TEST_LEVEL_GIVEN,
START_TIME_WID,
END_TIME_WID,
TEST_QUERY ,
QUERY_DESC,
Comments )
values
(
V_RUN_ID ,
V_QUERY_ID  ,
V_QUERY_NAME,
V_QUERY_STATUS ,
V_MAIN_TABLE_NAME ,
V_EXP_RESULT  ,
V_ACT_RESULT ,
V_RUN_ON_DT ,
TEST_LEVEL,
START_WID,
END_WID,
V_TEST_QUERY ,
V_QUERY_DESC ,
V_COMMENTS );


END;
```

Now i have two questions i have done everything except storing the values    `TEST_LEVEL`,`START_WID`,`END_WID` in the  which i commented in the procedure because one using them i was getting compiler error.
Question 1:-How to store `TEST_LEVEL`,`START_WID`,`END_WID` in the  (Answered with help of @Swapna answer.)
Question 2:-I will be running multiple queries on different tables and storing them in `V_ACT_RESULT` so i was think if there is a way to save all queries in some text file and then just import them here with some script.If anyone knows how to do this please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For statements like yours Select ... from << table_to_be_tested >> Isert into << table_to_be_tested >>.... you need to use dynamic SQL, e.g. EXECUTE IMMEDIATE or REF CURSOR.
Here's general example of sql statement built "on the fly" based on Oracle scott.emp table. You do the same for Insert/Update...:

```
DECLARE
  PROCEDURE get_total(p_tab_name VARCHAR2:= 'scott.emp'
                     , p_column_name VARCHAR2:= 'JOB'
                     , p_list VARCHAR2:= '''MANAGER'', ''CLERK''')
IS
  v_sql           VARCHAR2(200);
  cnt             NUMBER:= 0;
BEGIN
 dbms_output.put_line(p_list);
  v_sql:= 'SELECT count(*) total FROM '|| p_tab_name ||
           ' WHERE '||p_column_name||' IN ('||p_list||')';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql INTO cnt; 
  dbms_output.put_line(cnt);
END;
BEGIN
 get_total;
END;
/

Output:

'MANAGER', 'CLERK'
 7
```

Oracle docs - you can find more on the topic using Oracle docs, search...: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/executeimmediate_statement.htm#LNPLS01317

In short you cannot use placeholders in your procedure for table name. You need to write bunch of code...

Comment: i am not a expert on sql so can you elaborate in a little code block how to store those three in the table i tried EXECUTE IMMEDIATE and got a compiler error.

Comment: @Auguster - I hope example helps. You count query needs to be converted to dynamic query as in my example. Same with your insert. Declare another variable and build your insert then use execute immediate: EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO '|| table_name|| ' VALUES...(...)';

Answer (score 1):

START_WID and END_WID is defined as number in procedure input parameter and its getting inserted into date fields. That might be one of the reasons why you are getting a compilation error. It would help if you share the error too.

Comment: Now if you can please help with the second question.Any suggestions are welcome too

Comment: This is just a suggestion for your second issue, might not be the best approach. You can store all the table names and queries you want to execute against them in a table and loop through them and do what you are doing right now to insert into the test result table. I don't think you have to write it to a file and import it back.

Comment: Here is the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/11_dynam.htm) for dynamic query.